# Thread don't put in Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to spawn multiple thread that are waiting through time.sleep and put a random number in a queue. And then get those numbers from the queue and divide them by 10000.

But this is not working, when time.sleep is equal to 0, the random number is correctly inserted in the queue, however, when time.sleep is greater than 0 nothing is put in these queue.

```
import random
import time
import os
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Tempo(Thread):

    def __init__ (self, queue):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self._queue = queue

    def run (self):
            temporisation = random.randrange(0,4)
            time.sleep(temporisation)
            rand_range = random.randrange(0,1000)
            self._queue.put(rand_range)
            os.sys.stdout.write(str(rand_range) + " : time sleep : " + str(temporisation) + " put in queue\n")
            os.sys.stdout.flush()

def tempo_x(range_haute, queue):
    for x in range(0,range_haute):
            Tempo(queue).start()
    queue.put('exit')

def divise_10000(queue):
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
            rand_range = queue.get()
            if isinstance(rand_range, int):
                    os.sys.stdout.write(str(rand_range/10000) + "\n")
                    os.sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                    break

if __name__ == '__main__':

    queue = Queue()

    get_process = Process(target=divise_10000, args=((queue),))
    get_process.daemon = True
    get_process.start()

    tempo_x(10, queue)

    get_process.join()
```

**Output :**

```
230 : time sleep : 0 put in queue
92 : time sleep : 0 put in queue
763 : time sleep : 0 put in queue
881 : time sleep : 0 put in queue
213 : time sleep : 1 put in queue
124 : time sleep : 1 put in queue
584 : time sleep : 1 put in queue
57 : time sleep : 2 put in queue
583 : time sleep : 2 put in queue
735 : time sleep : 3 put in queue
0.023
0.0092
0.0763
0.0881
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: The location of `'exit'` in queue may not be where you think it is. What happens if you put `os.sys.stdout.write('put exit on queue\n')` just after `queue.put('exit')` ?

Comment: Your Process terminats at once as the `queue` is **empty**. Fill the `queue` bevor `get_process.start`.

Comment: @jamesj629 You are right, 'exit' is insert in the queue before the end of the tempo_x. tempo_x spawn 10 thread that sleep for a random int, it spawn the thread then put 'exit' in the queue. So only the thread that sleep for 0 second are placed before the exit.